# Xcode 8: How to pass data to a view controller without using a segue or storyboard?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

So I have this code that instantiates a view controller when a button is pressed:

```
@IBAction func addChapter(_ sender: Any) {
    let addChapterController = AddChapterViewController()
    self.present(addChapterController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Without a prepareForSegue, how do I pass data to this newly created view controller?

Comment: Set properties on the instance of the view controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `AddChapterViewController` you can create the variables that you want to change, for example:

```
class AddChapterViewController: UIViewController{
    var name: String?
    var id: Int?
    // ....
}
```

So you can use its properties now like this:

```
@IBAction func addChapter(_ sender: Any) {
    let addChapterController = AddChapterViewController()
    addChapterController.name = "Name example"
    addChapterController.id = 10

    self.present(addChapterController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Hi i tried this. But i am getting a nil value for the properties name and id if i try to access them in the viewDidLoad method of AddChapterViewController class.

Comment: @KKbot In this example, the properties `name` and `id` are only set when the user presses a button, if you want to set it's value in `viewDidLoad` you should move this snippet of code to there before calling the properties.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. Got around that problem.